# how to check if user input is in a dictionary

Tags: python

how do I check if a value that the user has given is in a dictionary of randomly generated numbers and that the key and value match?

```
card_numbers = {}

def create_card():
    first_half = 400000
    second_half = random_digits_gen(10)
    card_num = int(str(first_half) + str(second_half))
    pin_num = random_digits_gen(4)
    store_nums(card_num, pin_num)
    print('Your card has been created\n'
          'Your card number:\n'
          f'{card_num}\n'
          'Your card PIN:\n'
          f'{pin_num}')


def store_nums(number, pin):
    card_numbers[number] = pin


def check_nums():
    card_num = input('Enter your card number:\n')
    card_pin = input('Enter your pin:\n')
    if card_num in card_numbers.keys() and card_pin in card_numbers.values():
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('nope')

create_card()
check_nums()
```

What is the right way to check for this?

Comment: You just need `if my_key in my_dict`, calling `dict.keys()` is not necessary.

Comment: use `if card_num in card_numbers and card_pin in card_numbers[card_num]`

Comment: You can do something like this:``` if (card_num, card_pin) in card_numbers.items()```

Comment: @blorgon You still have to check that the user input value does match to the existing key.

Comment: @tahesse OP edited. But checking if the user input is in the dictionary *is* checking that it matches. I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @blorgon Sorry, I meant that the sole test if the key exists in the dictionary does not provide any information if the user input value and the stored value does match. So I think you have to add that one to the check.

Comment: @tahesse gotcha. Yeah before the edit, OP was just asking how to check if a value is in a dictionary. By "value" I assumed they meant it as a generic term, and not the latter half of a "key-value" pair.

Comment: @blorgon Alright, that's a fault on my end - thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ you have to chose how you store your card numbers and PIN. As leading zero can be important I recommend to store them as strings. Otherwise your pin number or card number first and second half could not stard with 0, without being shortened.

2/ second your card_numbers variable should be made global in each function, so the same variable is used in the whole piece of code.

3/ you have to change the pin comparison part like this:
card_numbers[card_num] == card_pin

Here is the whole code, I just replaced random_digits_gen calls by hardcoded numbers to make things easier for testing. Here the card number is 4020 and pin is 1111.

```
card_numbers = {}

def create_card():
    first_half = "40"
    second_half = "20" ## random_digits_gen(10)
    card_num = str(first_half) + str(second_half)
    pin_num = "1111" ## random_digits_gen(4)
    store_nums(card_num, pin_num)
    print('Your card has been created\n'
          'Your card number:\n'
          f'{card_num}\n'
          'Your card PIN:\n'
          f'{pin_num}')


def store_nums(number, pin):
    global card_numbers
    card_numbers[number] = pin


def check_nums():
    global card_numbers
    card_num = input('Enter your card number:\n')
    card_pin = input('Enter your pin:\n')
    if card_num in card_numbers.keys() and card_numbers[card_num] == card_pin:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('nope')

create_card()
check_nums()
```

Output is:

```
Enter your card number:
4020

Enter your pin:
1111
Success!
```

Comment: thanks this helped... I looked in my code and found that I didn't have everything the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check that the `card_num` input by the user exists in the `card_numbers`. In case of existence, check that the values does match. Your function should look like this:

```
def check_nums():
    card_num = int(input('Enter your card number:\n'))
    card_pin = int(input('Enter your pin:\n'))

    stored_card_pin = card_numbers.get(card_num)  # does return None if key is not found
    if stored_card_pin is not None:
        print('Success!' if stored_card_pin == card_pin else 'nope')
```

Comment: Thank you @goalie1998, I fixed it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Also, don't forget to either convert your inputs to integers (or dictionary keys and values to strings)

Comment: @goalie1998 True, but I simply copied that part of the code from OP. Let  me fix that as well. From the code, I'd infer that both should be `int` though. You got the eyes of hawk. :)

Comment: That was more for OP than for you to fix. OP needs to decide which/where in the script to make that determination.

Comment: To make things easy and take into account possible leading 0, I recommend you use strings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are checking if the card number and the card pin are part of the dictionary. Also as @goalie1998 mentioned, you need to convert the input into integers.

The way your code is currently setup, if you have the following examples:

`card_numbers{100:20,200:40}`

and your inputs are `100` and `40`, your code will be True.

Let's examine it.

The first part of the if statement

`if card_num in card_numbers.keys()` will be True as `100` is a key.

It will then check the second part:

`and card_pin in card_numbers.values()`

This will also be True as `40` is one of the values in the card_numbers dictionary. However, `40` is not part of `100`.

The correct way to check this will be as shown below.

```
if card_num in card_numbers and card_pin in card_numbers[card_num]:
```

The way python checks is from left to right. So it goes through the first if statement (`if card_num in card_numbers`). If this is `True`, then it checks if `card_pin` is in `card_numbers[card_num]`.

If `card_num` is not in `card_numbers`, it exits the if statement. So it never goes to check if `card_pin` is in `card_numbers`.

By keeping the correct order of the if statement, you can avoid error handling situations.

The updated code will be as follows:

```
def check_nums():
    while True:
        try:
            card_num = int(input('Enter your card number:\n'))
            card_pin = int(input('Enter your pin:\n'))
            break
        except:
            print('input not a number. retry')
    if card_num in card_numbers and card_pin in card_numbers[card_num]:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('nope')
```

Comment: Don't forget to either convert your inputs to integers (or dictionary keys and values to strings)

Comment: Absolutely. Thats a given. Didn't realize the code didnt take care of it. Adding it now. Thx for highlighting it

Comment: That was more for OP than for you to fix. OP needs to decide which/where in the script to make that determination.

Comment: To make things easy and take into account possible leading 0, you have to use strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check that `card_num` exists in the dictionary and then compare the `card_pin` against that card number:

```
def check_nums():
    card_num = input('Enter your card number:\n')
    card_pin = input('Enter your pin:\n')
    if card_num in card_numbers and card_pin == card_numbers[card_num]:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('nope')
```

Comment: do not forget to check you compare the same kind of variables . strings and/or int. Here strings should be easier because this takes into account leading 0.